# Why does my CSS not work in an EJS file rendered inside an if statement

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to apply CSS to this EJS file but no matter what kind of styling I apply nothing works. Here is the code sample:

**itemEdit.ejs**

```
<%- include("partials/header.ejs", {title: ` - Items`, body_id: `items`} )%>
<%- include("partials/navbar.ejs", {bg: `dark`})%>

<div class="edit-container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Edit item</h1>
        <a href="/items">
            <<<-Back to items page</a>

    <form action="/itemEdit/item-edit/<%= item._id%>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter item name">
        <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="enter item description">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer.ejs")%>
```

**index.ejs**

```
app.get('/itemEdit/:id', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    // Query for session user object
    User.findById({ _id: req.user._id },
        (err, doc) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err); }
            else {
                const { userInventory } = doc

                for (let i = 0; i < userInventory.length; i++) {
                    if (userInventory[i]._id == req.params.id) {
                        res.render('itemEdit.ejs', {
                            item: userInventory[i], // Item object
                            user: doc // Session user object
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
})
```

This is what I added to the CSS to test if it's working.

**style.css**

```
.edit-container {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Even after I added the red background it doesn't show that styling. The CSS is loaded from the header.ejs file and I can confirm that it works on all the other EJS files except this one. Could it be because I have it inside an IF statement and that's why the CSS won't apply and even the FOOTER won't display properly even though it works on all the other EJS pages.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

After playing around in the console, I noticed that the app is treating the itemEdit.ejs file as a folder. See screenshot:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1HY0.png). What would be the reason for this? I never made it into a folder, it's only a simple EJS file.

Comment: how are you adding the css file ?

Comment: @DivineSoul It's inside its own public folder and is being read by the partial header file that's used across all the pages and it adds the styling. The only pages where it isn't working is the `itemEdit.ejs` that I shared in my post and another `EJS` page that also has the route inside a `for loop` similar to the `itemEdit` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this format : `href='/stylesheets/style.css'` ?
without the '/' it will look in the relative path which would become

```
'/itemEdit/stylesheet/style.css'
```

you can also check the path of the requested file by opening the debug window and going to the `'network'` panel, then do a `F5` to reload the page and you'll see all files being loaded

at this point you can click on specific file (in this case `style.css`) and check the full path that the browser is using to get the file

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the new format you suggested didn't fix it and I refreshed the page while in the `'network'` panel and I can confirm that the `style.css` file is being loaded and that the path is accurate.

Comment: I owe you an apology, your method of adding the slash worked. If I'm understanding this correctly, by adding a '/' we're making it an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with express if added as dependencies.

$npm install express

Make a folder named "public" in your projects folder.
In public folder you can create your css folder.

Then in your index.ejs:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Basically gives EJS permission to load static files in public folder and no more need for internal css.

Comment: I do have the CSS in my "public" folder. I don't believe it's that that's giving me this issue. But I do appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I narrowed it down to this line of code in the header partial file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`.
I had my css in a public folder as well so there shouldn't be a problem.

Adding a `/` in front of css folder like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">`

Fixed it without destroying the rest of the code. I don't know what that does i guess i got more reading to do. Hope this helps